# Accuracy of Orbital parameter calculations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, astrophysics, orbital-motion, planets

I'm working on a program that calculates the orbital parameters of orbital bodies, and have run into an issue:

I'm looking up and comparing my programming results with the orbital parameters of Earth and the Sun, and realised that different equations seem to give me different results:

To elaborate, take the following parameters:

`rmin` or Periapsis: 147.09 x10^9 metres
`rmax` or Apoapsis: 152.10 x10^9 metres
`ε` or Eccentricity: 0.0167

`a` or Semi-major axis: 149.60 x10^9 metres

If I apply the following equation from [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes) to obtain the Semi-minor axis, or `b`:

$$b = a\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^{2}}$$

I receive the following value:
149600000000 * sqrt(1 - (0.0167^2)) = **149579137573** (On Google calculator)

However if I obtain the Semi-minor axis using the Semi-latus rectum, or `p` from [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion):

$$ b = \frac{p}{\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^{2}}} $$

I obtain the following value:
149548054813 / sqrt(1 - (0.0167^2)) = **149568912904**

When we look at the difference between these two numbers, there is a highly noticeable difference of **10224670** between them! I know this is based from Earths approximated orbital values, which we don't know the true values for, (I grabbed them from [**here**](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/earthfact.html))

My question is, which of these two equations are **more accurate**, **WHY??**, and are there any other equations that find the Semi-minor axis, also explaining  the accuracy of them.

I saw the same thing for a few of the other properties (I think it was Semi-major) and I ended up with bizarre differences. I **am** calculating this right (according to the page) but seem to be getting huge error margins. Any ideas?

**NOTE:**

I obtained the Semi-latus rectum, or `p` using the equation from **[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion)**:

$$ p = \frac{r_{min} \cdot r_{max}}{a} $$

(152100000000 * 147090000000) / 149600000000 = **149548054813**

Please bare in mind, I'm only in Year 11, so I may not understand everything you throw at me, also acknowledging that this is a pretty massive task for me to undertake to begin with; this also isn't any form of homework (thankgod), I'm doing this under my own taking.

Comment: use $$ p = \frac{{{b^2}}}{a} $$ to check your value for p I think rmin and rmax are probably inaccurate...

Comment: Thankyou @BradS, will do! Any reason why exactly?

Comment: no, actually I'm trying to figure that out right now myself. I thought it was a matter of significant digits but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @BradS Well thankyou for the help. I have absolutely **NO** idea at all, this is the question!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to start using scientific notation.  In your first calculation $b_1 = 149579137573 = 1.49579 \times 10^{11} m$, in your second calculation, $b_2 = 149568912904 = 1.49569 \times 10^{11} m$, this better highlights that the difference in one part in $10^5$, or about $0.001%$.  This may still be important (i.e. show an error), but it's a better way to think about things!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the values that you've been given have been rounded. If I calculate everything based off of Semi-major axis and Eccentricity as given on the Earth page of wiki everything checks out except the values I calculate for Aphelion and Perihelion do not match the values they've given on the wiki page. So I think you need to use one set of rounded numbers or the other but not both. If you're interested my calculations look like this:

Comment: (see in 'answer' below, couldn't get the formatting right in a comment. sorry)

Comment: @BradS Hmm... I'm using the data that NASA has to get best results. Is there a better place I could use potentially?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But if they only give you 4 or 5 significant digits than that's the extent of the accuracy that you can expect. They probably give you an average because it varies depending on when you make the measurement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are given a number with only 3 significant figures (eccentricity of 0.0167 - only the 1, 6 and 7 are "significant") then you know the number is not 0.0168 or 0.0166 -- and that gives you an approximate range of accuracy you can expect.

Each of your methods gives you $1.496 \times 10^9 ~\rm{m}$ - accurate to 4 significant digits. That's better than you should expect.

The accuracy of your result is only ever as good as the accuracy of the inputs. Some of the data you have is given to 5 significant digits - that will give you the "more accurate" results.

I recommend that you learn about error propagation. There are millions of resources online for this - a relatively basic introduction can be found [here](https://physics.appstate.edu/undergraduate-programs/laboratory/resources/error-propagation)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I have been *really* busy with the project and school. I actually totally forgot about error propagation and simply kept the numbers intact without thinking!

Answer (score -2):

$a = 149598023$

$e = 0.0167086$

$p = a(1-e^2)$

$p = a(0.99972082268604) = 149,556,258.62576513369892$

$b = \frac{p}{ \sqrt{1-e^2}}$

$ = \frac{p}  {0.99986040159916324190990908617052}$

$ = 149,577,139.35522085944399314340085$

$b = \sqrt{p*a}$
  = 149,577,139.35522085944399314340085

$pa = rmax * rmin$

$22,373,320,617,691,160.86368910923516 =  rmax * rmin$

$rmax = \frac{p}{(1-e)}  = \frac{p}{0.9832914}    =152,097,596.5270978$

$rmin = \frac{p}{(1+e)}  = \frac{p}{1.0167086}    =147,098,449.4729022$

$152,097,596.5270978 * 147,098,449.4729022 = 22,373,320,617,691,160.86368910923516$

Comment: So many insignificant digits... this is not helping.

Comment: All digits are significant to me.

Comment: Also, I was showing him/her that the equations are accurate if you use enough digits. This was per our conversation in the comments. This comment was too large to be a comment so I put it as an answer but it is not expected to be an answer.